# Animate view in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-animation

I have a relativelayout which is basically a listview and a button. My listview is set to `"match_parent"` in width and height. And my button is shown at the bottom of the screen with `layout_alignParentBottom = "true";`.

I would like to achieve a similar effect as Google Chrome has with its url bar. I mean, I would like to be able of making the button invisible when scrolling down and visible when scrolling up, as chrome does.

I've tried overriding `onScroll()` method for the listview and using `TranslateAnimation()` but I can't get the effect I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) library for android.
Use it in your xml:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />
```

Then attach it to your listView:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.attachToListView(listView);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for... but thanks anyway. Hopefully someone will now what I mean.

Comment: Android floating action button which reacts on scrolling events. Becomes visible when an attached target is scrolled up and invisible when scrolled down. -- isn't this what you want?

Comment: Yes it is but not the exact way, I mean, I wanted a button with text on it and kind of Holo style because I am not upgrading to Material Design yet and I don't like to mix styles...

Comment: you can try to change the drawable by `android:src="@drawable/myimage"` or remove it and add text `android:text="@string/text"`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a scroll listener on ListView,and write the scrolling method in it.Like hide the button while listview scrolls up.But you can't implement a TranslteAnimation on listview directly,while FileAfter is true.It will cause a complex problem.